# Are these two examples equivalent (volatile + synchronized increment vs synchronized fetch + increment)?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, synchronized, volatile

I have researched about the differences between `synchronized` and `volatile`, and have wrote an example without volatile, which I believe is equivalent to the example with volatile (due to the additional synchronization on the fetching)

**Version with Volatile**

```
public class Volatile extends Super {
    private volatile int xCounter;
    private volatile int yCounter;

    @Override
    public int getXCounter() {
        return this.xCounter;
    }

    @Override
    public int getYCounter() {
        return this.yCounter;
    }

    @Override
    public void incrementXCounter() {
        synchronized (getLockXCounter()) {
            this.xCounter++;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void incrementYCounter() {
        synchronized (getLockYCounter()) {
            this.yCounter++;
        }
    }
}
```

**Version without Volatile**

```
public class NonVolatile extends Super {
    private int xCounter;
    private int yCounter;

    @Override
    public int getXCounter() {
        synchronized (getLockXCounter()) {
            return this.xCounter;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getYCounter() {
        synchronized (getLockYCounter()) {
            return this.yCounter;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void incrementXCounter() {
        synchronized (getLockXCounter()) {
            this.xCounter++;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void incrementYCounter() {
        synchronized (getLockYCounter()) {
            this.yCounter++;
        }
    }
}
```

**Super Class**

```
public abstract class Super {
    private final Object lockXCounter = new Object();
    private final Object lockYCounter = new Object();

    protected abstract int getXCounter();
    protected abstract int getYCounter();
    protected abstract void incrementXCounter();
    protected abstract void incrementYCounter();

    Object getLockXCounter() {
        return lockXCounter;
    }

    Object getLockYCounter() {
        return lockYCounter;
    }
}
```

Specifically, **Is there equivalent between the two examples provided on the following two points?**

**1)** Performance

**2)** Thread-Safety

Please provide an example which shows lack of thread safety if thread safety is not guaranteed in one of the examples.

Comment: @ScaryWombat I will clear that up on the original post (the fetchers are not using synchronized, only the incrementors, which need to be synchronized due to being non-atomic).

Comment: In general, synchronization is more expensive than reading a volatile. Are you using this just as an example? Because the AtomicInteger class is probably your best bet to begin with (it uses Unsafe class under the covers).

Answer (score 1):

`volatile` is considerd as a weaker form of synchronization. You use volatile to ensure the visibility of the current value when reading, so you use locking for all mutative operations and volatile for read-only operations. Where locks only allow one thread to access a value at once, volatile reads allow more than one, so when you use volatile to guard the read code path, you get a higher degree of sharing than you would were you to use locking for all code paths. So the performance of the former outperforms the latter.

Comment: So the functionality of both are the same (as in, both are thread safe), but the latter suffers a performance penalty due to the fact that multiple (safe) fetches cannot be performed at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

1. Put simply, first one is slow for writers, fast for readers, second is balanced for both (hypothetically). You should note that on some architectures `volatile` is essentially the same thing as synchronization in implementation because the underlying system still needs to retain memory consistency, so it might as well not matter if you're using either example in terms of performance. All that said, it's just me waving my hand around in the air and hypothesizing, you should test and benchmark yourself on your target systems and see for yourself. Measure now, optimize later.
2. Yes it's thread safe. First is more weakly consistent, it's not always guaranteed to see the most up-to-date value because you could possibly read during a compound update, but as long as writers do not interfere with one another it doesn't really matter because it can only be a maximum of 1 behind the "actual" value. Of course, sometimes being strongly consistent matters, so you should again consider how this factors into your own target systems.

Equivalency is a little more difficult to answer, but "it depends." Again, sometimes `volatile` is basically the same thing as `synchronized` on the underlying system, but that's not really guaranteed by the JMM. What is guaranteed is that writes will be visible to readers, writes will be atomic with respect to other writes (but NOT with respect to reads).

In the end, you seem to be motivated by performance, but you should note that `volatile` is not free. Again, I should stress that it still entails synchronization of the underlying hardware, which is "relatively" expensive no matter if it's a lock or a `volatile`.

---

Or you could just use an `AtomicInteger` and get the best of both worlds: quick reads and quick writes (except in certain scenarios, you should look into `LongAdder` for high contention). The choice really is yours.